# Rows with a start_date and end_date, need to return records that fall within a date range

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that contains tasks, each task has a date_start and date_finish field.

I need to construct a query which will take a passed in date and return all rows if that passed in date falls between the date_start and date_finish.

Does this make sense?

I have been trying to use standard date type querys such as:

```
SELECT *
FROM project_task
WHERE project_task.date_start >= '2013-10-10' AND project_task.date_finish <= '2013-10-10'
```

but it doesn’t return the correct results and using BETWEEN does not work either because I need it to take into account both fields (date_start and date_finish) not just the one.

I think it may only be the WHERE part of the query I need.

Comment: Use 2 BETWEENs, 1 for date_start and 1 for date_finish

Comment: You mean like this: select *
  from project_task
 where start_date between start_date and end_date
    or end_date between start_date and end_date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made a simple mistake, you got the order of your operators wrong:

```
SELECT *
FROM project_task
WHERE 
    project_task.date_start <= '2013-10-10'      -- start should before the test date
AND 
    project_task.date_finish >= '2013-10-10'     -- and finish after the test date
```

**Explanation**

If the date checked is between date_start and date_finish, then we must have reached at last the start date. We could have a later date too. That means the

```
date_start will be lower or equal than the date checked
```

And the second check said: the finish date musn't have passed. So

```
date_finish has to be greater or equal than the date checked.
```

With your original query you will only get projects that start and end on '2013-10-10'.

**[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e7b41/1)**

Comment: are you sure? I cant see that

Comment: @user794846 I've added an explanation and a demo.

Comment: Ok this is looking better, I am testing this and so far it seems to be working. Sometimes you cant see the wood for the trees. Ill accept this later if it keeps working.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Now datetime = '2013-10-10T00:00:00'

SELECT *
FROM project_task a
WHERE @Now >= a.Date_Start
AND @Now < isnull(a.Date_Finish, '9999-12-31T00:00:00')
```

Comment: This does not return all records correctly, only some of them.

Comment: Do you have an example of a start and end date that it should be returning that is being missed?, I have added an ISNULL around the date_end as I guess this could be NULL if the project is not finished?

Comment: Ok so my answer will give you where '2013-10-10' is between the start and end dates - what you asked for, VMai's answer will give you where '2013-10-10' is after the end date

Comment: You could shorten his query if Date_Start is ALWAYS before Date_Finish the just date_finish >= '2013-10-10' would do?